# Alterar parte do texto de uma label

Tags: jquery

Tenho a seguinte label criada por um plugin

```
<label>
Buscar:
<input type="search" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="" aria-controls="Pedidos">
</label>
```

O que eu quero fazer é alterar apenas o "Buscar" por algo X.

Tentei da seguinte forma mas sem sucesso

```
var Label = $('#Pedidos_filter').find('label').html();
$('#Pedidos_filter').find('label').html(Label.replace('Buscar','x'));
```

Como poderia estar procedendo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O jQuery é limitado no que respeita a capturar elementos `text node`, então tens de usar o método `.contents()` e ir buscar o primeiro elemento/node dessa array e mudar-lhe o `textContent`.

Assim:

```
$('label').contents()[0].textContent = 'x';
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ajj854c2/